# First row fixed DataTable on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

i want to have first row locked/fixed in Flutter.
How can i do that?

```dart
 child: Container(
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: DataTable(
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```dart
Scaffold(
 body: Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child : Column(
     children: [
       Row(
        children:[
          Text("Some text here"),
        ]
       ),
       Expanded(
         child: SingleChildScrollView()
      )
     ]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that in DataTable. I would suggest you try using [DataTable2](https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2) package, which allows fixed table row headers and columns as well.

Click [here](https://github.com/maxim-saplin/data_table_2/blob/main/example/lib/screens/data_table2_fixed_nm.dart) for sample code.